# Calling static factory method with unknown class

Tags: java

Hi I have an abstract class which have many subclasses. Id like to make this abstract class' constrcutor private and create factory method. How should this method look like to work in the same way in every sub-class? If I make:

```
return new AbstractClass();
```

I get error saying: Class is abstract, cannot be instances... Should I use reflection?

Comment: you can't create objects of abstract classes. You can only create reference variables.

Comment: You cannot use "new AbstractClass()" , it's creating a new object which is not possible for abstract classes.

Comment: You could use reflection and write your own code that does that. I for one would use a dependency injection libraries though. Like Guice or Spring.

Comment: Get rid of abstract class and use interface.

Comment: I KNOW I CANNOT CREATE ABSTRACT INSTANCES. Question was other, please read again. @EnnoShoiji Ok I will see, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access the constructor of the abstract class from the subclasses using the `super` keyword.

```
public SubClass() {
    super(); // this will call AbstractClass()
    // something else that you want to do for this subclass
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in the comments, you can't use the `new` keyword with  an abstract class. When you use new, you need to know the real type.

You could either implement the factory method in the abstract base class and make it decide which non-abstract subclass to return based on the parameters passed to the create method and/or some internal logic.

Or you could make the factory method itself abstract and implement it in every non-abstract subclass to return an object of that type.